# Covariance calculation - Excel / R

Tags: r, excel, covariance

I have the following two datasets for which I would like to compute the covariance.

```
a <- c(320,
       324,
       340,
       314,
       322,
       342,
       302,
       317,
       338,
       326)
b <- c(120342,
       114397,
       102328,
       134786,
       132034,
       98078,
       138965,
       136753,
       114566,
       128435)
```

In R when I compute this value, I have the following output :

```
> cov(a, b)
[1] -161632.6
```

In Excel I have a very different value for the covariance :

```
=COVAR(<column A>,<column B>)
-145469.3
```

If I use `COVARIANCE.P` in Excel I have the same number.

**I was wondering why both programs are returning a different value for the covariance.**

After some investigation, I noticed that this difference was due to the number of degree of freedom used by both software.

```
> sum((a - mean(a))*(b - mean(b))) / length(a)
[1] -145469.3
> sum((a - mean(a))*(b - mean(b))) / (length(a) - 1)
[1] -161632.6
```

R is using one degree less of freedom, why?

Comment: R calculates the **sample variance** by default which is same with `COVARIANCE.S` in Excel. Only difference between sample variance and population variance is the minus one in denominator. You can have a look at [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/198452/why-sample-variance-has-has-n-1-in-the-denominator) question for more details.

Comment: This too:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/92286/validating-correlation-in-excel explains the reason